# urllib3 equivalent to requests' Session

Tags: python-3.x, session, python-requests, urllib, urllib3

Is this a thing? I heard that urllib3 is faster than requests, so I am trying to switch over, but I need a session feature. I am trying to keep **cookies persistent** on most requests, but some requests I have a special need for them to not have the same cookies.